# WooCommerce update order review hook doesn't return changed billing country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to fetch the customer's billing/shipping country so I can run my own logic based on the selected country. The code below works however when a customer changes their billing/shipping country the old value is returned it's not until you reload the page or change the country again (which returns the previously set value) do you get a different result.

It appears the new value isn't set when this hook runs?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'remove_eu_cart_tax', 51, 51 );
function remove_eu_cart_tax( $cart ) {
    $country_list   = array('AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'EL', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IT', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MT', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SE', 'SI', 'SK');

    $shipping_country    = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    $shipping_country    = empty($shipping_country) ? WC()->customer->get_billing_country() : $shipping_country;

    if(in_array( $shipping_country, $country_list) {

    }

});
```

How can I get the correct country after a user has made a change to this input?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to just access the post data from the checkout page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'remove_eu_cart_tax', 51, 51 );
function remove_eu_cart_tax( $cart ) {

   $postedData = array();
   $vars = explode('&', $cart);
   foreach ($vars as $k => $value){
       $v = explode('=', urldecode($value));
       $postedData[$v[0]] = $v[1];
    }

    $country_list   = array('AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'EL', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IT', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MT', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SE', 'SI', 'SK');

    if(!empty($postedData)){
      if(!empty($postedData['ship_to_different_address'])){
        $shipping_country    = $postedData['shipping_country'];
      } else {
        $shipping_country    = $postedData['billing_country'];
      }
    } else {
      $shipping_country    = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
      $shipping_country    = empty($shipping_country) ? WC()->customer->get_billing_country() : $shipping_country;
    }

    if(in_array( $shipping_country, $country_list) {
       // logic here
    }

});
```